# MySQL select 7 days before event and 7 days after event

Tags: mysql, events

I have database with dates of birthdays and namesdays of users. I want to select all users who had birthday/namesday from 7 days ago to 7 days in future this select works but I don't know how to solve the problem with users who have birthday/namesday 31.12. for example. PHP will return "USER had birthday 3 days before", this select works well only 7 days before end of year and 7 days after new year. Thank you very much for help.

```
SELECT `name`, `surname`, `gender`, ('birthday') AS event,
  DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(REPLACE(`birthday`, YEAR(`birthday`), YEAR(NOW())))) AS diff
FROM `users`
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(REPLACE(`birthday`, YEAR(`birthday`), YEAR(NOW()))))
BETWEEN -7 AND 7
UNION
  SELECT `name`, `surname`, `gender`, ('namesday') AS event,
    DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(REPLACE(`namesday`, YEAR(`namesday`), YEAR(NOW())))) AS diff
  FROM `users`
  WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(REPLACE(`namesday`, YEAR(`namesday`), YEAR(NOW()))))
  BETWEEN -7 AND 7
```

Comment: There is `DAYOFYEAR`. But how do you intend to handle leap years (persons having their birthday on Feb 29th? now being Feb 29th?)? All this has to be specified and implemented carefully, I've seen websites taken offline due to such bugs, the last time this year on... Feb 29th ;-)

Comment: I think that DATEDIFF(X,Y) works like TO_DAYS(X)-TO_DAYS(Y), so there is 29.2. included

Comment: Yes. But, again, any code to treat this probably must consider four (!) cases: { birthday is (not) on Feb 29th } x { `NOW()` is (not) Feb 29th }. Plus, the computation differs depending on whether the current year is a leap year or not. Difficult to get this straight in an elegant fashion.

Comment: but 29.2. is not the primary problem, I haven't any user with birthday on 29.2. and 29.2. will be in next 4 years, more actual problem is with end/start of year

Comment: You see. This is how bugs happen. The wraparound problem is trivial compared to what you face with the leap year issue. And what you write... "will be in next 4 years", this just scares me. Do you think the bugs you are introducing by plain ignorance will not affect you?

Comment: in this select the part "DATEDIFF(NOW(), DATE(REPLACE(`birthday`, YEAR(`birthday`), YEAR(NOW()))))" will work like DATEDIFF('2012-05-15', '2012-02-29') and result will be 76 so it works in leap years!

Comment: How does MySQL react to `DATE('2011-02-29')`? (Honestly, I don't know. Your options strongly depend on that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question.
This is what I've done so far. I'm not sure if it's perfect but it could be a good start. Give it a try.

```
select *,
if(right(birthday,5)>=right(curdate(),5),concat(year(curdate()),'-',right(birthday,5)),concat(year(curdate()+interval 1 year),'-',right(birthday,5))) as next_birthday,
if(right(birthday,5)<right(curdate(),5),concat(year(curdate()),'-',right(birthday,5)),concat(year(curdate()-interval 1 year),'-',right(birthday,5))) as prev_birthday
from users
having next_birthday 
between curdate() - interval 7 day and curdate() + interval 7 day
or prev_birthday 
between curdate() - interval 7 day and curdate()
```

Comment: right is a string function that returns you last five chars of a string (in this case of date of birth mm-dd)

Comment: this is a bit convoluted, there are existing methods that will do this without relying on parsing out the date manually.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mfJ4b3uZ @nickrulez I used your code, it works, thank you but I think that it is very long :) (35 lines)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is fairly straight forward, use to_days(). This way relies on the calendar set in the DB, so you don't have to worry about leap years.

```
select
    `name`, `surname`, `gender`, ('birthday') AS event,
    to_days(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(`birthday`), '-',day_of_month(`birthday`))) as current_yr_bday 
FROM `users`
WHERE 
    to_days(concat(year(current_date()),'-',month(`birthday`), '-',day_of_month(`birthday`))) between to_days(date_sub(current_date() interval 7 days) and to_days(date_add(current_date() interval 7 days
```

Answer (score 0):

Brute force method would be to calculate your diff for YEAR-1, YEAR, YEAR+1 and then check if any of these 3 sums satisfies your condition.

Not so brute force would be to do the difference between now and first of Jan and calculate years accordingly to that.

Interesting problem, i'll come back if i think of something else.